# ActiveWorkbook vs ActiveWindow

Tags: excel, vba

What is the difference between `ActiveWorkbook` and `ActiveWindow`?

Sometimes I feel they are the same.

Comment: Because a workbook can have more than one window, sometimes the distinction is between `ActiveSheet` and `Activewindow`. Here's a rather esoteric example I blogged about:http://yoursumbuddy.com/sheetactivate-event-doesnt-fire-between-multiple-windows/

Answer (score 3):

- Windows and Workbooks do have different properties/methods (although some are the same) so you can't always do with one what you might with the other.
- ActiveWindowClose will not always close the workbook (for example if you have two or more windows open in the activeworkbook for example).
- Also, if you use `Windows(wbName).Activate` then you are also at the mercy of your windows settings ("Hide extensions for known file types") which will determine how your windows name appears (i.e. with or without the `.xls(x)` extension for example) which may cause the code to bug out.
- Generally much better to avoid referring to the window unless you need to (e.g. to change the Height).

Comment: Thanks @Dhruvin Sukhadiya. that's a helpful generalization